# Is there any difference between these Differential $dx^2$ and $(dx)^2$?

Tags: terminology, notation, mathematics

- is there any difference between these Differential $dx^2$ and $(dx)^2$!?
- what is relation between them?

Comment: Why are you asking it at Physics.SE? Isn't Maths.SE correct place for it?

Comment: Note that in the context of (one-dimensional) Riemannian manifolds, the flat space metric tensor $(dx)^2$ is always written as $dx^2$.

Comment: Does the square I'm the first one apply to the whole or just the x. I'm assuming from context that it does, but i want to be sure and avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

$dx^2=2xdx$

Instead $(dx)^2$ is usually intended as a second order correction and typically is neglected in calculations.