# Differential of square $dw^2$or square of differential$(dw)^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry

in [Curved space](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Curved_space&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop)
it seems $dw^2=(dw)^2$ how is it possible!?

$$x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=\kappa^{-1}R^2,$$
$$dw=w^{-1}(xdx+ydy+zdz),$$
$$\kappa^{-1}R^2-(x^2+y^2+z^2)=w^2,$$
$$dl^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2+dw^2,$$

$$dl^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2
+\frac{(xdx+ydy+zdz)^2}{\kappa^{-1}R^2-x^2-y^2-z^2}$$

**Remark:**
in general as i know $dx^2=2xdx$ so $dw^2$ should be:

$$dw^2=(2w)w^{-1}(xdx+ydy+zdz)=2(xdx+ydy+zdz),$$
but here

$$dw^2=(dw)^2=w^{-2}(xdx+ydy+zdz)^2,$$
how is it possible?

Comment: This question(v1) appears to be caused by [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45768/2451) post.

Comment: Because $d(x^2)$ may be written as $2x\,dx$, as you seem to know, it would be silly to reserve the symbol $dx^2$ for that, too. Instead, $dx^2$ always means $(dx)^2$. What does the question "how is it possible" mean? What kind of an answer do you want? How would you answer a similar question "how is it possible that 2+2=4", for example?

Comment: @Qmechanic elected :D

Comment: Congrats, Qmechanic, it's good news!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31594/2451

Answer (score 4):

That wiki article is unfortunately very poorly written. In any event, the convention in relativity is *always* that $dx^2$ is shorthand for $(dx)^2$. The same holds for $dw^2$, $dt^2$, $d\varsigma^2$, $d\aleph^2$ or whatever else you see. The reason is you are rarely interested in the differential of a square (getting your second line from the first is an exception to this), but squares of differentials come up all the time. If perchance $dx^2 = d(x^2)$ in some case, then it is merely coincidence.

This is unfortunately *not* the operator precedence I was taught in high school with differentials and deltas, but that's how it is.

Comment: Yes, well one could also write $\text{d}x\otimes\text{d}x$ if one wants. You add that that's not the operator precedence you were taught, but that's not really true as you already have it in $\frac{\text{d}^2 f(x)}{\text{d}x^2}$. Or maybe by "this" you mean it the other way around, but whatever. I like your dAleph, haha, is there an operator with Leibnitz rule for larger cardinals? :D

Comment: @NickKidman Alternatively $\mathrm{d}x \wedge \mathrm{d}x$ in the notation I sometimes use, since it is ultimately a wedge product of exterior derivatives.

Comment: What is? Here we are concerned with the metric, right? And the line element requires no anti-symmetrization.